# How to detect when video texture is done in A-Frame?

Tags: aframe

I want to transition out of the videospheres once the video ends, is there any event that is triggered when a video is over or some other way to go about doing this?

`<a-scene>
  <a-assets>
    <video id="vid" src="a.mp4"></video>
  </a-assets>
  <a-videosphere src="#vid"></a-videosphere>
</a-scene>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the events from the native video element.

```
var video = document.getElementById('vid);
video.addEventListener('ended', function (evt) { 
  // ...
});
```